# Is there RPC API endpoint to request how much resources account uses?

Tags: smart-contract, accounts, rpc, api, apiendpoint

Is there any way to track or get information about current user account resources consumption using RPC API? I.e. how many operations can be executed with the current tokens or how much RAM or CPU is taken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can refer to [the EOSIO documentation for get_account](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_account)

`curl --request POST --url http://localhost:8080/v1/chain/get_account --header 'accept: application/json' --header 'content-type: application/json' --data '{"account_name":"eosio"}'`

The results show RAM/NET/CPU current usage and maximum available.